# toString all the object datas

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose

I have an object (json) like this in node.js:

```
var data = {
    string : "name",
    number : 123456789 ,
    n : null ,
    bool : false ,
    bool2 : true
};
```

But I need to conver it to something like this:

```
{
    string : "name",
    number : "123456789" ,
    n : "null" ,
    bool : "false" ,
    bool2 : "true"
};
```

I used this codes but not works.

```
for ( var index in data ){
    data[index] = data[index].toString();
};
// or this
data.toString();
```

How can I fix it?

UPDATE

this data object is created as a new mongoose schema.

Comment: First, that is not JSON. Then, why would you need to do this?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(data, String)` should do

Comment: I print it with `condole.log(JSON.stringify(data,String))` and the output was only : ""

Comment: @Bergi The `replacer` function is a bit odd in that it first gets called for the entire object.  As a result, that would wipe the object out.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: You're right. It would need to be a `(x)=>Object(x)==x?x:String(x)` kind of replacer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine, except for one thing: `null` doesn't have `.toString()` method. So, it's best to use `String` instead:

```
for ( var key in data ){
   data[key] = String(data[key]);
};
```

`String` is a string constructor. It takes anything and produces a string representation of it.

## Update

But this solution won't work for complex data structures. Though, if you need a JSON string, then you could use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with tricky [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter):

```
function replaceWithString(k, v) {
  if ((typeof v === 'object') && (v !== null)) {
    return v;
  } else {
    return String(v);
  }
}
JSON.stringify(data, replaceWithString);
```

and if you want to make it pretty:

```
JSON.stringify(data, replaceWithString, 2);
```

**N.B.** As *Bergi* noticed in comments, you could use `Object(v) === v` instead of `(typeof v === 'object') && (v !== null)` to check that `v` is an object.

## Update2

It looks like `data` in your example is a `mongoose` document.

The problem with `mongoose` is that it wraps all its object with the whole pack of nasty getters and setters to make them look like plain JS objects, which they are not.

So, if you're working with `mongoose` documents, you should call [.toObject()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) or [.toJSON()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON) before trying to do anything with it:

```
data = doc.toObject(); // converts doc to plain JS object
```

Though, my second solution with `JSON.stringify` should work anyway, because `stringify` calls `.toJSON()` automatically.

Comment: Thank you.but when I use `String` or `toString` the code didn't work and cause error.I'm using node.js express framework.

Comment: @Elyas74 it's strange, because `String` should not produce an error, no matter how did you call it. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @Elyas74 Node.js was built on top of the V8 engine therefore `String` / `toString` are definitely in there.

Comment: @James it's a normal behavior of V8 to produce an error on `null.toString()`, but it should work fine with `String`.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I thought the OP meant it was throwing an error due to those methods not being there....regardless, using `String` shouldn't throw an error.

Comment: When I use it in simple ways it works fine, but when I want to use `String(data[index])` this error occur in my server : `TypeError: Cannot call method 'modify' of undefined ...
`

Comment: @Elyas74 are you sure that you're getting this error in `data[key] = String(data[key])` call?

Comment: There is only one way `data[key] = String(data[key])` could produce such an error - if your object have some nasty setters. Modules like `mongoose` sometimes wraps their objects in such a way.

Comment: exactly I use mongoose schema for this object,how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var index in data) {
  if (data[index] === null) {
    data[index] = "null";
  }
  else if (data[index] === undefined) {
    data[index] = "undefined";
  }
  else {
    data[index] = data[index].toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var val = null;
for(var key in data){
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        val = data[key];
        val = val === null ? 'null' : (val === undefined ? 'undefined' : val.toString());
        data[key] = val;
    }
}
```

It simply converts `null` to "null" and `undefined` to "undefined"
Note that values of your object must be a primitive data type for this to work. btw, this will work fine for your example.

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

should work.

when doing

```
data[index].toString();
```

you are referencing a null on the third run. null has no such method toString().

Comment: `stringify` will not give the result requested.  `null`, `true` and `false` will not be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd answer with a code that's a bit different:

```
for(var x in data){
    data[x] = ""+data[x]+"";
}
```

Works.